# Why is this regex matching an incorrect pattern?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a bunch of regex within PHP, with the first clause being:

```
if (preg_match('#^/index#i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || preg_match('#^/(ACT)|(NSW)|(NT)|(QLD)|(SA)|(TAS)|(VIC)|(WA)/$#i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
```

Now, say `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is equal to `/VIC/events/`; this is for some reason matched by this first clause. Why? Shouldn't that only match it if it was equal to `/VIC/` as I added the end of line character `$`?

Comment: I wouldn't of thought "/VIC/events" was matched by either of these patterns

Comment: @Dale: At first glance it doesn't look like it should match, but look again carefully (or try it out) and you will see that it does in fact match.

Comment: @MarkByers But the `$` wont match `/VIC/events`

Comment: @Dale: Try it: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm. Read my answer below for the explanation.

Comment: @MarkByers Forgive me if i'm totally failing to understand here but it still wont match `/VIC/events`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parentheses around your alternation:

```
'#^/(ACT|NSW|NT|QLD|SA|TAS|VIC|WA)/$#i'
```

Without the parentheses `^a|b|c$` means `(^a)|b|(c$)` which is not what you intended.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `/$` is being grouped with the last option. At the moment, your second condition will be truthy if a match to any of the following regexen is found in the string:

1. `^/(ACT)`
2. `NSW`
3. `NT`
4. `QLD`
5. `SA`
6. `TAS`
7. `VIC` (this one matches)
8. `(WA)/$`

The sample string you have provided *does* in fact contain a match to #6 - `VIC`, so the whole condition evaluates to true. As Mark has pointed out, you need to group the central values using parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parentheses to mark your groups, like this:

```
'#^/((ACT)|(NSW)|(NT)|(QLD)|(SA)|(TAS)|(VIC)|(WA))/$#i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```

This matches anything that starts and ends with ACT, NSW, NT, QLD, SA, TAS, VIC and WA.

As yours is matching:

```
'#^/(ACT)|(NSW)|(NT)|(QLD)|(SA)|(TAS)|(VIC)|(WA))/$#i',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Starts with ACT or NSW, NT, QLD, SA, TAS, VIC or ends with WA.